# XPath rule in XML Plugin for Sonar

Tags: xml, plugins, sonarqube

I am having trouble configuring the [Sonar XML plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/XML+Plugin). I am trying to run it against the simple xml doc below. I have created a copy of the default xml profile and am trying to write a custom XPath rule. I have made sure that the rule is activated. However, I cant seem to get the XPath rule to fail.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<bookstore>

<book>
  <title lang="eng">Harry Potter</title>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>

<book>
  <title lang="eng">Learning XML</title>
  <price>39.95</price>
</book>

</bookstore>
```

The XPath expression which I am using is:

```
//@lang='eng'
```

It does seem to be checking the file as on the dashboard I am able to see the number of lines and the file. However there are never any rules which fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into the same problem, I built the plugin from source and used that jar instead of the one provided.